# Mono-atomic 1D lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics

I have a question regarding this topic. In our script we study the case of mono-atomic (diatomic etc) 1D lattice for the case of nearest neighbor interaction. In  all our examples this is the case we study.
I am curious to know how things change when we take into consideration the force that acts upon an atom of the chain from all the other atoms. How would we be able to write an equation of motion for an atom in an arbitrary position? Is it wrong to limit yourself within the BZ, since the 1d lattice can have Avogadro number amount of atoms?

Any link or book regarding this case would help me understand this case,which is the real case.

Comment: Are you talking about waves in 1D lattice? The calculations of lattice energy shown in introductory Solid State texts take into account the interactions with the rest of lattice. See Madelung constant for ionic crystals.

Comment: i am talking about the equation of motion of one atom in the whole chain, when we consider that every other atom acts on it. We should have a generalized equation of motion for this arbitrary atom. And i assume that by taking n,the number of atoms in the chain towards infinity, we must have a dispersion relation.And that is what i am after. I want to know how this dispersion relation looks mathematically and graphically different then the one a monoatomic 1D lattice.

Comment: You have to add to the forces between nearest neighbors those with all the additional atoms of the chain. At the formal level, it is quite simple. As far as I remember in Kittel's book on Solid State Physics you should find the relevant formulae for the 1D case.

Comment: i was able to derivate how $\omega$ looks like!